# why I can't access wcf hosted in windows service?

Tags: wcf, windows-services

I have a WCF service hosted in windows service.

when I am trying to access the service I am getting below error message.

***No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:9002***

Inner Exception

***There was no endpoint listening at http://localhost:9002/MainService/Service that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.***

But endpoints has been defined in App config of WCF as below.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="MainService.CalculatorService">
        <endpoint address="CalculatorService" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="MainService.ICalculator">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:9002/MainService/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" httpsGetEnabled="True" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

web config of the client

```
<client>
    <endpoint address="http://localhost:9002/MainService/CalculatorService"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_INoiseCalculator"
    contract="Service.ICalculator" name="BasicHttpBinding_INoiseCalculator" />
</client>
```

In Controller I am accessing service as per below

```
MainService.CalculatorClient proxy = new MainService.CalculatorClient();
proxy.getDetails();
```

I have opened up the port in the firewall as well.

I can't figure out what's wrong because when service gets self hosted in WccSvcHost it works fine but after deployment it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that there is something wrong with the service running state. For verifying this, we could talk about the client endpoint at first.

```
<client>
    <endpoint address="http://localhost:9002/MainService/CalculatorService"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_INoiseCalculator"
    contract="Service.ICalculator" name="BasicHttpBinding_INoiseCalculator" />
</client>
```

The contract is Service.ICalculator, while the namespace you are using to instantiate the client proxy is MainService

```
MainService.CalculatorClient proxy = new MainService.CalculatorClient();
proxy.getDetails();
```

Is the client service endpoint automatically generated by adding service reference? Why the namespace is incongruity?
I suggest you generate the client endpoint again by adding service reference on the client-side, with this, we can check if the service is working well.
[image]
About calling the service by adding service reference.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/accessing-services-using-a-wcf-client
Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.

Comment: Thanks! Endpoints was generated automatically. I have renamed those in the question for security reasons. I figured out the issue by trying to generate wsdl as mentioned. issue was the base address. also I had to use one of the overload while initiating to pass binding name (binding name needs to be used when you have a multiple endpoints which in my case was not this was weird because I had only one endpoint.).